# using jqgrid in spring mvc3.0

Tags: jquery-plugins

Can anybody tell me how to implement jqgrid in spring mvc3.0????
If anybody has got a sample application for the same....

Comment: Does jqGrid support the server side sorting, paging, filtering???

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial I've just written :)

I hope you like it. Here's the link:
[JqGrid and Spring 3 MVC Integration Using Annotations Tutorial](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/jqgrid-and-spring-3-mvc-integration.html)

Here's the url: http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/jqgrid-and-spring-3-mvc-integration.html